# Calculate intercept location and time

Tags: vector-spaces, collision-detection

I want to calculate the coordinates and time where object **B2** can intercept object **B1**.

Asuming the following:

All coordinates are in pixels

**B1:** Moves from coordinates A1 to A2, it has a speed of 2 pixels per hour and starts moving at 15:00.

**B2:** Moves from A3 to B1 and has a max speed of 1,5 pixels per hour and starts moving when it can intercept **B1**

**A1:** has the coordinates 20,45 (X,Y)

**A2:** has the coordinates 60,86 (X,Y)

**A3:** has the coordinates 55,78 (X,Y)

Results of the calculations I would like to achieve:

The time (00:00 - 24:00) and coordinates (X,Y) **B2** is able to intercept **B1** while both moving on a straight line, keeping in mind that both objects have a different movement speed.

[image: overview]

Comment: What does it mean to move "from A3 to B1" when B1 is constantly moving? Does B2 travel along a straight line, or a pursuit curve, or something else?

Comment: B1 wants to intercept B2, both objects want to travel along a straight line. To futher explain; all the A points are planets, B1 and B2 are spacecraft thus radius etc, can be left out when it comes to calculating when it can intercept it or not. From point to point calculations, center to center if you will.

Comment: The picture helps clarify the problem. If B2 can start moving at any time (including before B1) then you can have it intercept wherever you want. What are the constraints on when B2 can start moving?

Comment: B2 can only start moving when it can intercept B1, that is when B1 going from A1 to A2. There are no other constraints that apply to B2. Keep in mind that the movement speed on B2 can be dynamic, just as B1 can have a different movement speed. Hope this clarifies some parts

Comment: I think you are saying B2 cannot start moving before B1 does. If so, the earliest possible intercept point occurs at $P$ on line $A_1A_2$ such that $A_1P = \frac43 A_3P$. To intercept at any other point between that point $P$ and $A_2$, B2 just has to start later or move slower. If B1 is able to change its speed after B2 has already committed to a line of travel, you cannot be sure when the interception will occur; you cannot even guarantee that B1 will ever reach the interception point unless you specify a minimum speed.

Comment: Getting closer to the calculations iam looking for. Iam going to draw a new scematic that discribes my situation better, I will also add the other calculations ive already done that allow dynamic input. Also, the movement speed is a constant and cannot vary. To explain the use for this calculation: A1,A2,A3 are planets and B1 and B2 are spacecraft. B1 moves from planet A1 to A2; A3 picks up this travel and sends ship B2 to intercept. Both ships have different engines thus a different movement speed.

Answer (score -1):

B2 can intercept B1 as long as A3-A2 distance <= 75% of (15,0) to A2 passing by A1

Let's call the point where B1 start A0 :

```
B2 intercept B1 <=> dist(A3,A2) <= 75/100 (dist(A0,A1) + dist(A1,A2))
```

(Since 1.5 = 75% of 2)

Comment: I am sorry, maybe you misunderstood my question; The question is not if B2 is capable of intercepting B1, The question is how to calculate the the exact time and coordinates B2 is able to intercept B1.